# PHP/Mysql query? how do I count the number of zeroes in a row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quiz site which save score.
I want to do a chart showing what exercises have not been done using the score '0'  to represent undone.
How do i count the zeros so far i have

```
$sqlquery="SELECT * FROM Algebra WHERE  email='$currentEmail' AND username='$currentUser' AND 0;";
```

Comment: `AND 0`?  Surely you mean `AND someColumn = 0`?

Comment: `and 0` would evaluate to `and false`, and fail out the entire expression. @user3697958 exactly how is an "undone" exercise represented? no records in the db? You can't count what doesn't exist, unless you can refer (e.g. join) to something else that DOES exist.

Comment: How do you store your _exercises_  ?

Comment: Please share the relevant part of your database structure (e.g. what columns are in the `algebra` table?)

Comment: The exercises are stored as js on files but the results at the end of the quiz are store via ajax to php to mysql. I want all scores above zero in the row which represents each user

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlquery="
SELECT * FROM Algebra 
WHERE email='$currentEmail' 
   AND username='$currentUser' 
   AND exercises=0";
```

Of course, if the column is not exercises, this will not work, you will have to put in the name of your exercises column

Comment: Well I want all my columns checked and summed up

Comment: The table is called Algebra two columns are email and username then the others algebra.0 changing the digit at the end